# PHP regexp: matching everything until a word appears

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In PHP I'm looking to match everything until a certain word appears:

```
$text = "String1

                         .

                  testtesthephepString2 Here";

$faultyregexp = "#String1(.+)String2 Here#";

preg_match($text, $faultyregexp, $result);
```

Now I want to match everything between String1 and String2, but for some reason this doesn't work.

I'm thinking you could do something like **`#String1(^String2 here+)String2 here#`** if you know what I mean :) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that by default `.` does not include newline characters. If you want `.` to match all character, you need to specify the `s` modifier ([`PCRE_DOTALL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)):

```
/String1(.+)String2 Here/s
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I was looking for. I can even use it in other places with great benefit! Thank you again :)